# expandable and collapsable uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to achieve something like an expandable and collapsible `UITableViewCell`. The part of collapsing and expanding on user tap has been achieved, but what i am looking for is the feature of showing more and less.

That is, when the `UITableViewCell` has not expanded to show full view, the word "more" should be displayed. When the `UITableViewCell` is expanded, it should show the word "less" at the end. So whenever the user taps on more, then only the `UITableView` should expand and vice versa. Any ideas on how I could do this? Something like on web pages. When u click on more link it expands the area and lets u see its entire content.

Comment: Please look at: http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=482

Comment: Look at the WWDC 2010 videos...

Comment: Eh... this isn't really a duplicate of the linked question, and I've flagged for mod attention on those grounds... but reading this carefully, I'm not really sure what the question here is even asking. -1

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on iWasRobbed's answer, you are looking for WWDC 2010 Session 128, Mastering Table Views, which you can officially find at [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).

It includes a demo of expanding table cells by updating the values returned by `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` then calling:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

on the `UITableView`. Since you don't need to change which rows are shown, you don't need to include any code between begin and end. Once `endUpdates` is called, the heights of all the rows are re-calculated by calls to `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for each row.

The video includes examples of how to animate the updates, including how to disable the animations.

Comment: @Dougles i saw that video but couldnt the source code. i found [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) at Apple's Sample Codes but it is very complicated. can you help me please?